# Why "мамы здесь нет", not "мама здесь нет"

Tags: падежи, abessive-case, genitive-negative

I have encountered the sentence "Mom is not here anymore" translated as "Мамы здесь больше нет".

Why "мамы" and not just "мама"? Is it in genitive case?

Comment: Many synthetic language speakers when asked how to find grammatical case (падеж), just offer to ask a question. But they do not realize, that asking the right question requires to know grammatical case. I think there is no simple answer. What is even worst - grammatical cases have different questions between languages (Russian > Благодарить кого, Bulgarian > Благодаря кому).

Comment: the differences aren't that critical, and attestation to that is the fact that people do manage to master foreign languages, the majority of verbs applications i reckon still follow identical case paradigms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The thing in in Russian the phrase "Mom is not here anymore" is sort of answering the question "Whom do we miss here" rather than "Who is not here?" - it quite a subtle difference regarding the fact that the usage of "whom" is declining, but luckily it's still a thing in English so I can use it for explanation )

- whom? - кого (genitive)
- who? - кто (nominative)

Answer (score 14):

Negative construction with "нет" always needs genitive in Russian and answers the question "нет кого/чего", and not "нет кто" which is ungrammatical:

> Нет кого? - Нет мамы.

However you can say "Мама не здесь" (as opposite of "мама здесь") which is totally correct.

Answer (score 6):

When you use negation meaning that something or someone is absent, especially strong negation (not here anymore) it's natural in Russian to use **нет**, which demands *genitive* **нет (кого,чего?) мамы, хлеба.**
Otherwise you can say

> Мама не в Москве,она в Саратове. Or 
>   Мамы нет в Москве, она в Саратове.