# "Реальности не существует" - why a genitive here?

Tags: грамматика, abessive-case, genitive-negative

If you take a look at the book [«Верховный алгоритм: Как машинное обучение изменит наш мир»](https://books.google.ru/books?id=YIaMDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1&pg=PA191#v=onepage&q&f=false), in the first line of page 191, you'll read:

> "..., что объективной реальности вообще не существует"

Why is **реальность** in its genitive form? Shouldn't it be nominative:
("*объективная реальность вообще не существует*"), as here **реальность** is the subject of verb существует?

Comment: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12641/why-мамы-здесь-нет-not-мама-здесь-нет

Comment: You are meeting the phenomenon called "negative genitive," which is a phrase you can search for to find further discussion of this construction in Russian.

Comment: it's also known as Abessive or Caritive and Privative case

Answer (score 3):

This is a type of sentence which is called impersonal (subjectless).

Please [take a look](http://www.russianforeveryone.com/Rufe/Lessons/Course1/Grammar/GramUnit15/GramUnit15_2.htm).

With negation of the verb `существовать` this form of sentence is especially common.

It's also a normative pattern for negation of the verb `быть (бывать)`. While `there's me` is translated as `я есть`, `there's no me` is translated as `меня нет` where `меня` is Genitive of `я`.

The English `there's (no) me` is also a [subjectless type of sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impersonal_verb#In_English).

Comment: So English actually follows same pattern as Russian by using objective  case. They should say "It is I". "It's me" is incorrect from grammar point of view, because "to be" requires use of nominative "I": "It was I who allowed Alliance to know the location.."